# Is there an online tool to help purchasing option spreads?

Tags: options, stock-markets, call-options, option-strategies, spreads

I'm pretty new to futures trading and I'm wondering if there is an online tool to help look at various spread options contracts?

I'm interested in getting some experience trading futures with pretty low risk and from the research I've done, making a long call spread seems to be a pretty safe bet on a stock I'm bullish about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options Industry Council allows you to input your own data on a 4 leg position:
http://www.optionseducation.org/tools/position_simulator.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the investopedia.com simulator lets you do options trading but I don't think you can do spreads.

http://www.investopedia.com/simulator

Looks like http://www.wallstreetsurvivor.com has a simulator that might work here.